# Filtered List items add to collection in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have following code snippet to fetch data as IEnumarable list and filter them using LINQ and insert those details to List/

```
  IEnumerable<User> listUsers = ..// From DB 
  List<User> filteredUsers = new List<User>();

  if (listUsers != null)
  {                          
     foreach(var user in listUsers)
     {
        filteredUsers = listUsers.Where(x => x.GroupID == item).ToList();                            
     }                    
  }
```

How to insert these Each `filteredUsers` item to collection , I tried something like below but this is with compile time errors, how to do this properly

```
      IEnumerable<User> listUsers = ..// From DB 
      List<User> filteredUsers = new List<User>();
      IEnumerable<User> salistUsers = new List<User>();

      if (listUsers != null)
      {                          
         foreach(var user in listUsers)
         {
            filteredUsers = listUsers.Where(x => x.GroupID == item).ToList();   
            salistUsers.Add(filteredUsers);                         
         }                    
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `salistUsers` type from `IEnumerable<User>` to `List<Users>` and use [List.AddRange(collection As IEnumerable(Of T))](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx) method.

```
IEnumerable<User> listUsers = ..// From DB 
List<User> salistUsers = new List<User>();

if (listUsers != null && !listUser.Any())
{                          
     var filteredUsers = listUsers.Where(x => x.GroupID == item).ToList();
     salistUsers.Add(filteredUsers);                                            
}
```

Comment: this should be inside for loop or outside ?

Comment: there is no need for `foreach` lopp.

Comment: Error `'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<User>' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<User>' could be found`

Comment: Checkout answer again.

Comment: there was some mistake in previous code, can you look at now

Comment: again error as `The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<User>.Add(User)' has some invalid arguments`

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `.Add` with an `IEnumerable`, salistUsers sould be a `List`:

```
List<User> salistUsers = new List<User>();
```

The `Add` method is used to add a single object.

Try `AddRange` instead, which allows you to add a list:

```
if (listUsers != null && !listUser.Any())
{                          
     var filteredUsers = listUsers.Where(x => x.GroupID == item).ToList();
     salistUsers.AddRange(filteredUsers);                                            
}
```

Comment: this is not working `The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<User>.Add(User)' has some invalid arguments`